# Footer in multiple languages free WordPress

Tags: wordpress, footer, multilingual, translate, polylang

I'm trying to figure out how to create a footer that changes from english to spanish. I'm working with the astra theme and the polylang plugin which both let me create all the pages and menus with the 2 languages, but not with the footer. I'm trying to figure out how to configure it without having to pay for the pro version of the astra theme (it's outside my client's budget)
Any ideas?

I found some solutions that add some if to the functions.php but couldn't make them work, my php knowledge is pretty basic, and I couldn't find a way to adapt it to my own problem.

I also tried using the translatepress pluging, but it doesn't work on top of polylang, or I would have to translate the whole website again.

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to post this question at the wordpress stackexchange site instead

Answer (score 0):

Create two different footer templates:

Copy the original footer.php file from your theme directory and rename it as footer-en.php for the English , Duplicate the footer-en.php file and rename it as footer-es.php for the Spanish.

In your theme's functions.php file add the following code:

```
function custom_astra_footer_template( $file ) {
    $language = get_locale();
    if ( $language === 'es_ES' ) {
        $file = 'footer-es.php';
    } else {
        $file = 'footer-en.php';
    }
    return $file;
}
add_filter( 'astra_get_footer_template', 'custom_astra_footer_template' );
```